# Linking PayPal Refund Transactions To the Parent Transaction

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, paypal

I have a list of PayPal transactions.

```
Date                    Name        Type                            Status          Currency    Gross   Fee Net         FromEmailAddress    ToEmailAddress              TransactionID       CounterpartyStatus  AddressStatus   ItemTitle   ItemID  PPAmount    InsuranceAmount VAT AuctionSite BuyerID ReferenceTxnID      InvoiceNumber   CustomNumber    Balance     AddressLine1    AddressLine2    TownCity    State       Postcode    Country
2014-10-09 12:30:35.000 Joe Bloggs  Shopping Cart Payment Received  Completed       GBP         16.72   -0.43   16.29   customer@gmail.com  sales@mycompany.co.uk       63U4AAAAAAAA4602    Non-US – Verified   Confirmed       Shopping Cart       0.00        0.00                                                                        1122982         20,915.27   22 Greens Street                AnyTown     AnyCounty   AA11 8HF    United Kingdom
2014-09-29 11:55:48.000 Joe Bloggs  Refund                          Completed       GBP         -3.59   0.05    -3.54   customer@gmail.com                              0DF00BBBBBBBB772W                                                              0        0       0                               8MF7DDDDDDDD7635U   579649                          49,194.56
2014-09-28 12:48:59.000 Joe Bloggs  Shopping Cart Payment Received  Completed       GBP         17.76   -0.45   17.31   customer@gmail.com  sales@mycompany.co.uk       20W1CCCCCCCC6710M   Non-US – Verified   Confirmed       Shopping Cart       0.00        0       0.00                                                                1122982         47,463.42   22 Greens Street                AnyTown     AnyCounty   AA11 8HF    United Kingdom
2014-09-28 12:25:26.000 Joe Bloggs  Shopping Cart Payment Received  Partially Refunded  GBP     43.74   -0.81   42.93   customer@gmail.com  sales@mycompany.co.uk       8MF7DDDDDDDD7635U   Non-US – Verified   Confirmed       Shopping Cart       0.00        0       0.00                                                                1122982         47,371.52   22 Greens Street                AnyTown     AnyCounty   AA11 8HF    United Kingdom
2014-09-15 15:02:27.000 Joe Bloggs  Refund                          Completed       GBP           -64.00    1.22    -62.78  customer@gmail.com                          7CY0EEEEEEEE48450                                                              0        0       0                               8C01GGGGGGGG8893T   574745                          29,783.89
2014-09-11 15:16:13.000 Joe Bloggs  Shopping Cart Payment Received  Completed       GBP         21.66   -0.61   21.05   customer@gmail.com  sales@mycompany.co.uk       62A5FFFFFFFF4763X   Non-US – Verified   Confirmed       Shopping Cart       0.00        0       0.00                                                                1122982         26,350.34   22 Greens Street                AnyTown     AnyCounty   AA11 8HF    United Kingdom
2014-09-04 18:04:48.000 Joe Bloggs  Shopping Cart Payment Received  Refunded        GBP         64.00   -1.42   62.58   customer@gmail.com  sales@mycompany.co.uk       8C01GGGGGGGG8893T   Non-US – Verified   Confirmed       Shopping Cart       0.00        0       0.00                                                                1122982         13,891.47   22 Greens Street                AnyTown     AnyCounty   AA11 8HF    United Kingdom
```

In most cases I can look for a `Status` of `Completed` and `Sum` the results to get a total income figure for a given date range. I can also `Sum` a results set to give me a total for Refunds `Status = 'Completed' AND Type = 'Refund'`

Where I am having a problem is getting a list of transactions that have been `Partially Refunded` and the amount refunded. `ReferenceTxnID` is meant to hold the `TransactionId` of the parent transaction it refers to, but this is not always the case. The refund can occurs at anytime so I cannot use `Date`, customers can make multiple transactions so I cannot use `FromEmailAddress`, `CustomNumber`  or any part of the address. Another thing that is making this more confusing for me is that a single transaction may have multiple `Partial Refunds`

Ideally what I would like is a list of sales transactions with columns that show refunded totals.  This is what I have been playing with so far (or what is left of it after going round and round in circles):

```
 Select t1.Date, t1.Name, t1.Status, t1.Gross, t1.Net, t1.Fee, IsNull(t2.Gross, 0) As RefundGross, ISNULL(t2.Net,0) As RefundNet, IsNull(t2.Fee,0) As RefundFee, t1.TransactionID, t1.PPAmount from 
  tblPayPalTransactions t1 LEFT JOIN tblPayPalTransactions t2 
    ON (t2.ReferenceTxnID = t1.TransactionID) AND (t2.Type = 'Refund')
    WHERE t1.AuctionSite = ''   --Can be zero length string or 'Ebay' I never want these together
    AND Cast(t1.[Date] As Date) BETWEEN '01 Oct 2014' AND '31 Oct 2014'
    And (t1.Status = 'Completed' or t1.Status = 'Partially Refunded')
  --AND t1.Name = 'Joe Bloggs' --So I can see particular transaction results by customer name
  --AND  IsNull(Cast(t2.Gross As Decimal(8,2)), 0) < 0  --So I can see just those with a refund
  Order By t1.[Date]
```

As long as there is a `ReferenceTxnID` this is nearly there (except for multiple Partial Refunds)

Type of results I need:

[image]

What I am looking to SO for is suggestions as to how I get around the transactions that have missing `ReferenceTxnID` using the data set above. I am struggling to match the refund to the original transaction when that is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PayPal "[TransactionSearch](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/)" API to get all the refund transaction id's related to the one parent id . You need to pass the original transaction id in the request and you will get all the related refund payments id's in response . I have included the example request and response for one transaction that has five partial refunds attached to it .

**NVP Request:**

```
USER=XXXXXXXXXXXX&PWD=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&SIGNATURE=XXXXXXXXX&VERSION=109.0&METHOD=TransactionSearch&STARTDATE=2014-08-12T00:00:00Z&TRANSACTIONCLASS=All&TRANSACTIONID=8VX52781A08183223
```

**NVP Response:**

```
L_TIMESTAMP0=2014-11-13T13:47:34Z
L_TIMESTAMP1=2014-11-13T13:46:37Z
L_TIMESTAMP2=2014-11-13T13:45:34Z
L_TIMESTAMP3=2014-11-13T13:38:21Z
L_TIMESTAMP4=2014-10-27T16:21:06Z
L_TIMEZONE0=GMT
L_TIMEZONE1=GMT
L_TIMEZONE2=GMT
L_TIMEZONE3=GMT
L_TIMEZONE4=GMT
L_TYPE0=Refund
L_TYPE1=Refund
L_TYPE2=Refund
L_TYPE3=Refund
L_TYPE4=Payment
L_EMAIL0=1Y607358F75052246@dcc.paypal.com
L_EMAIL1=1Y607358F75052246@dcc.paypal.com
L_EMAIL2=1Y607358F75052246@dcc.paypal.com
L_EMAIL3=1Y607358F75052246@dcc.paypal.com
L_NAME0=John Test
L_NAME1=John Test
L_NAME2=John Test
L_NAME3=John Test
L_NAME4=John Test
L_TRANSACTIONID0=2JG39166GV168310K
L_TRANSACTIONID1=49T02886PW5166630
L_TRANSACTIONID2=5KF36133MV122512D
L_TRANSACTIONID3=5HY460350V470314R
L_TRANSACTIONID4=8VX52781A08183223
L_STATUS0=Completed
L_STATUS1=Completed
L_STATUS2=Completed
L_STATUS3=Completed
L_STATUS4=Refunded
L_AMT0=-2.00
L_AMT1=-1.00
L_AMT2=-1.00
L_AMT3=-1.00
L_AMT4=5.00
L_CURRENCYCODE0=USD
L_CURRENCYCODE1=USD
L_CURRENCYCODE2=USD
L_CURRENCYCODE3=USD
L_CURRENCYCODE4=USD
L_FEEAMT0=0.06
L_FEEAMT1=0.03
L_FEEAMT2=0.03
L_FEEAMT3=0.03
L_FEEAMT4=-0.50
L_NETAMT0=-1.94
L_NETAMT1=-0.97
L_NETAMT2=-0.97
L_NETAMT3=-0.97
L_NETAMT4=4.50
TIMESTAMP=2014-11-13T13:47:40Z
CORRELATIONID=be00ca73dfa3a
ACK=Success
VERSION=109.0
BUILD=13443904
```

[image]

Comment: The data is downloaded via the `TransactionSearch` API in the first place.  We really don't want to make another call for every record that is missing a link to its parent transaction.  However, it has made me wonder how PayPal link the transactions when the `ReferenceTxnID` is missing.